# The procedure entiy point_JVM_GetClassMethod@24 could not belocated in the dynamic link library jvm.dll

Tags: java, selenium

Error message box throws while checking maven installed in command prompt.

after typing In commnad prompt 
mvn --version
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myserlf.

Solution : just update the older java vesrion to newer version.Update the path variable to newer version.

Faced annother issue after updating the java version. "unable to load native library the specified procedure could not be found".

Solution : Mapped the JAVA_HOME path with newer version of java.